# How to search the browser window object looking which object or variable has the searched-for value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I know I have a value say 'JohnSmith' stored in some object in the global space of the browser and I hit some breakpoint, how do I know which object or variable has a value of 'JohnSmith'? I have hundreds of objects and I don't want  to manually search for it in dev tools.
I have used some scripts in the console or snippet which traverse the all the objects but they all have failed to search properly or give some error message.

I tried [JS Runtime Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/js-runtime-inspector/iilpjebedgohcmlffhnkhbjhabkdhfmn?hl=en-US) which looked promising but it doesn't work at all in my version 61 of Chrome. Its subtab doesn't show up like their video shows.

Comment: Do you have a list of objects? or Do you want to check all objects in global space?

Comment: All of them or starting from an object. So window or the name of the object can be an  input parameter to the function doing the search

Comment: Could the searched for object be in a variable declared using `let`? These don't exist as window properties and I am unaware you can search their name space.

Comment: Traktor53 App is compatible with browsers which don't support let. So let is not used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a snippet I keep in devtools snippets panel:

```
{
  const checked = new Set();
  const dig = (value, o=window, path='') => {
    function check(v, name) {
      if ((typeof v == 'string' || typeof v == 'number')
      && String(v).toLowerCase().includes(value)) {
        console.log('%s in %s %o', v, path + name, o);
      } else if (v && typeof v == 'object' && v != window && !v.nodeName) {
        dig(value, v, path + name + '.');
      }
    }
    if (o && o.forEach) {
      for (let len = o.length, i; i < len; i++)
        check(o[i], `[${i}]`);
    } else if (typeof o == 'object') {
      for (const k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
        if (k.startsWith('webkit'))
          continue;
        try {
          const v = o[k];
          if (checked.has(v))
            continue;
          checked.add(v);
          check(v, k);
        }
        catch(e) {}
      }
    } else
      check(v);
  };

  console.group();
  dig('JohnSmith');
  console.groupEnd();
}
```

You can run devtools snippets by pressing Ctrl-Enter.

Comment: Has something changed in the web platform to break this? I haven't been having much success with this in 2021.

Comment: I use it occasionally, still works. You may need to modify the code though e.g. it doesn't look in key names.