# search string in any object while debugging mouse click event in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm exploring source code of website using **dev tools event listener break point**.
I want to search place in source code where variable/attribute/object/whatever with type `string` become contain my pattern.
In other words, i want kind of this:

```
Find('hahaha');
# processing
Result object: var a='you can't find me hahaha'
# or
Result object: var b='hahaha'
```

I know about `watch expressions`, but i must set there object name and full object value (*can't set a part of object value*)

---

**Why do i need it?** Because i'm writing scraper for [this website](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/anti-static-esd-bags-materials/605)
and can't get `s` parameter to open next page for category...And how i understand it's generating inside bunch of `javascript` files. That's how i want to understand process of generating parameters for next requests.

---

I'm such a newbie in `js` and `dev tools` at all, so if you can give any other workaround, i would be very glad

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536947) for a one-time search.