# How to traverse the runtime data graph created by a JavaScript app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, reverse-engineering

I am writing a Chrome extension that will add a couple of customizations to a commercial web app, which is implemented as a single-page application.

The SPA uses the [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) as part of its UI, and I want to tap into that implementation, by querying and modifying the content of the editor, via my Chrome extension (simply automating some operations that would usually be done manually).

My assumption is that, since Monaco Editor is open source, if I can reference the runtime object that it creates, my code should be able to interact with it via the same published APIs that the SPA is using. Is this a reasonable assumption?

Unfortunately, the bundled JavaScript code of the SPA is huge (over 100 minified bundles) and I am having difficulty finding and gaining runtime access to the editor object. I understand that it may be buried deep within a data graph created by the SPA, but I haven't seen anything within the global scope of the page that seems to represent the app's data graph.

I used `console.log()` (injected into the SPA) to log out the Window object, and searched for evidence of the data created by the app, but didn't find anything useful.

Apologies, I am a complete noob at this aspect of development, so maybe my assumptions are way off the mark.

I have read numerous tutorials on reverse engineering JavaScript apps, but they all tend to focus on the codebase, and I simply want to find and interact with the runtime data created by that codebase. Is there an easy way to discover and traverse the in-page data created by a JavaScript app?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe they add a JS object on document or DOM, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536947).